# In IE9, h1 element causes issue with button text alignment

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

So I ran into a strange issue that I have not been able to figure out for the life of me, Googled the crap out of it and found nothing.***This only seems to be an issue with IE9.*** I  haven't tired other versions of IE, but Chrome and Firefox do not have the same issue.

Adding an `<h1>` element to the page seems to mess up vertical text alignment inside buttons. The `<h1>` causes the button text to shift up by 1px.

In the Demo below, you can see that the two button on the left are ***not*** displaying correctly, because the text is shifted up by 1px (8px between the top-border and text, 10px between text and bottom-boarder). But the two buttons on the right ARE displaying correctly(9px between the top-border and text, 9px between text and bottom-boarder), because they are positioned absolutely (I have no idea why this fixes the issue). And if the `<h1>` is removed, then all buttons display correctly. It also seem to not effect buttons that are placed above the `<h1>`.

Does anyone know what is causing this? Is there another way to prevent this without `position: absolute;`?

I realize 1px off isnt the end of the world, but I hate not knowing why this happens...

[image]

[image]

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cS3Sg/3/)

**HTML**

```
<!--If the <h1> is removed, all are displayed correctly.-->
<h1>This is a test</h1>

<!--The text is off by 1px - 8px top/10px bottom-->
<button class="btn-off" type="button">BUTTON TEXT</button>
<input class="btn-off" type="button" value="BUTTON TEXT" />

<!--These will show correctly 9px top/9px bottom when posistioned absolute-->
<button class="btn-on-1" type="button">BUTTON TEXT</button>
<input class="btn-on-2" type="button" value="BUTTON TEXT" />
```

**CSS**

```
button, input{
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.btn-on-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 98px;
    left: 262px;
}

.btn-on-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 98px;
    left: 389px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/11/03/sub-pixel-fonts-in-ie9.aspx) about Sub-pixel Fonts in IE9.

> ClearType font rendering is used in all IE9 document modes; sub-pixel positioning is used only in IE9’s default standards mode. IE9’s compatibility modes—Quirks, 7, and 8—use whole-pixel text metrics.

I think this picture illustrates the issues pretty well (the "Your Browser" column was rendered with Chrome). But you can clearly see that the IE9 text is slightly higher then the other two columns...

[image]

So the answer is basically, your S.O.L. when it comes to IE9...

One solution would be to force the page to load in IE8 document mode. But this would prolly cause more problems then it would solve.
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

Answer (score -1):

this is only an idea why don't you write an CSS function for btn-off?

like this. 
CSS:

```
.btn-off-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 98px;
    left: 7px;
    }
.btn-off-2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 98px;
    left: 135px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn-off-1" type="button">BUTTON TEXT</button>
<input class="btn-off-2" type="button" value="BUTTON TEXT" />
```

on my side it work :D test ist on yours

Comment: Obviously I realize that would work, but the point of this question is to understand WHY this happens and also find a work-around that does not involve `position: absolute;`